# $.ajax call with c# ashx handler doesn't refresh results on second call, but has a success return code

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, ashx

I have been sat with a particularly hairy issue for a while now where a combobox isn't repopulating after an ajax call from an event elsewhere on the page.  I use DevExpress controls, but the only difference that causes is how I get the value of the fields.  Some (sanitised) code snippets that may help:

### aspx page:

```
///Populates the Combobox on demand using an AJAX call
function PopulateCombo(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/MyHandler.ashx',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            responseType : 'json',
            data : { userID: ASPxHiddenFieldData.Get('userID') },
            success: function(result, status){
                doPopulateCombo(result, status);
            },
            failure: onPopulateComboFailure //The call doesn't fail so this isn't used
        }); 
}

function doPopulateCombo(result,status){
alert(status); //this always ends up saying success
var obj = JSON.parse(result); //this parses fine, but on the second and subsequent calls it remains the old result set, so the combobox content never changes
    <%=ASPxComboBoxOrigin.ClientInstanceName%>.ClearItems();
    for(var k in obj){
        var listitem = new Array(obj[k].description,obj[k].detail);
        <%=ASPxComboBoxOrigin.ClientInstanceName%>.AddItem(listitem);
    }
```

### }

c#

---

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int UserID = int.MinValue;
        int.TryParse(context.Request["userID"], out UserID);
        List<AddressObject> returnlist = new List<AddressObject>();
        List<UserAddress> addresslist = UserAddress.GetAddressByUser(UserID);
        if (favouritelist != null)
        {
            foreach (UserAddress address in favouritelist)
            {
                returnlist.Add(GenerateAddress(address.AddressDescription, address.AddressDetail));
            }
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string addresses = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(returnlist);
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        context.Response.Write(addresses);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    { get  { return false;} } //I have tried both true and false

    private AddressObject GenerateAddress(string description, string detail)
    {
        var address = new AddressObject();
        address.description = description;
        address.detail = detail;
        return address;
    }
    private class AddressObject
    {
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string detail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

So what ends up happening is that the first time I select a user, the correct results are populated.  But when I change my user, I still end up with the list of the old user.  I have debugged through and can see that the first time round the breakboint in the handler gets hit, while on the second call, the handler doesn't get hit at all, but the ajax call still returns a success resul. though the result set is still the old one.  Any ideas how I can get the handler to ALWAYS be run and not use some results stored somewhere I don't know ?

Edit:

It seems the event handler only gets invoked the first time I navigate to the page.  Even navigating away and then back again doesn't call it.  I suspect it has something to do with the session.  Any thoughts are welcome.

Regards,

Comment: Browser tends to cache `$.ajax` GET response. To avoid caching add `cache:false` to `$.ajax` or change url like `url: '/MyHandler.ashx?a='+Math.random()`.

Comment: GREAT !  the cache:false did the trick !  Thanks a bunch.  I'd mark it as the answer, but alas, it is a comment